# How do I generate different columns based on multiple values from different columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, calculated-columns

I have the below dataset

```
data = {
'Partner': ['More', 'More', 'More', 'Reliance','Reliance','Reliance','Reliance','Reliance', 'More', 'More','Azfresh','Azfresh','Azfresh','Azfresh','Azfresh'],
'Brand': ['Biseliri','Biseliri','Biseliri','Biseliri','Biseliri','Biseliri','Kinili','Kinili','Kinili','Kinili','Biseliri','Biseliri','Biseliri','Kinili','Kinili'],
'Category': ['Milk','Milk','Milk','Milk','Milk','Milk','Water','Water','Water','Water','Water','Water','Water','Milk','Milk'],
'Product':['Milk_a','Milk_a','Milk_a','Milk_a','Milk_b','Milk_b','Water_a','Water_a','Water_b','Water_b','Water_a','Water_b','Water_a','Milk_b','Milk_b'],
'Yearweek':[202001,202003,202004,202001,202001,202002,202001,202002,202001,202002,202001,202001,202003,202001,202002],
'MRP':[50,45,50,50,45,45,100,90,150,150,110,150,100,50,50]}
```

I am trying to group data by partner, brand, category, product and get the decrease/increase in the MRP for the products and see for how long the price was decreased.

```
     Brand  Category    MRP Partner     Product Yearweek
0   Biseliri    Milk    50  More        Milk_a  202001
1   Biseliri    Milk    45  More        Milk_a  202003
2   Biseliri    Milk    50  More        Milk_a  202004
3   Biseliri    Milk    50  Reliance    Milk_a  202001
4   Biseliri    Milk    45  Reliance    Milk_b  202001
5   Biseliri    Milk    45  Reliance    Milk_b  202002
6   Kinili      Water   100 Reliance    Water_a 202001
7   Kinili      Water   90  Reliance    Water_a 202002
8   Kinili      Water   150 More        Water_b 202001
9   Kinili      Water   150 More        Water_b 202002
10  Biseliri    Water   110 Azfresh     Water_a 202001
11  Biseliri    Water   150 Azfresh     Water_b 202001
12  Biseliri    Water   100 Azfresh     Water_a 202003
13  Kinili      Milk    50  Azfresh     Milk_b  202001
14  Kinili      Milk    50  Azfresh     Milk_b  202002
```

So I tried doing the group by using the below code

```
groupeddata = df.groupby(['Brand','Category','Partner','Product','Yearweek']).agg({'MRP':'min'}).reset_index()
```

aggregated using min MRP just in case there are multiple MRP for the same group of data
Post this I used this code to generate the difference between the prices of products of the group to see the increase or decrease in price.
But I am not sure how to do it based on Yearweek.

```
groupeddata['diff'] = groupeddata['MRP'].shift(+1)-groupeddata['MRP']
groupeddata['diff'].fillna('0',inplace = True)
groupeddata['diff'] = groupeddata['diff'].apply(lambda x:int(x))
groupeddata['mrpoff'] = groupeddata['diff'].astype(str)+np.where(groupeddata.eval("diff>0"),"rs less"," rs increased")
```

But this is generating wrong df.

I am trying to achieve this: if the diff of price stays for more than 2 weeks then the noofdays should be 14, like in case of row 1 and 2 - the MRP increased only after 1 week of staying at 45. If the MRP stayed 45 for 202003 and 202004 and increased going forward then the noofdays should be 2 weeks * 7 days - 14 days

```
    Brand   Category    MRP Partner     Product Yearweek    diff    noofdays
0   Biseliri    Milk    50  More        Milk_a  202001         0    0
1   Biseliri    Milk    45  More        Milk_a  202003         5    7
2   Biseliri    Milk    50  More        Milk_a  202004        -5    0
3   Biseliri    Milk    50  Reliance    Milk_a  202001         0    0
4   Biseliri    Milk    45  Reliance    Milk_b  202001         0    0
5   Biseliri    Milk    45  Reliance    Milk_b  202002         0    0
6   Kinili      Water   100 Reliance    Water_a 202001         0    0
7   Kinili      Water   90  Reliance    Water_a 202002        10    7
8   Kinili      Water   150 More        Water_b 202001         0    0
9   Kinili      Water   150 More        Water_b 202002         0    0
10  Biseliri    Water   110 Azfresh     Water_a 202001         0    0
11  Biseliri    Water   150 Azfresh     Water_b 202001         0    0
12  Biseliri    Water   100 Azfresh     Water_a 202003        10    7
13  Kinili      Milk    50  Azfresh     Milk_b  202001         0    0
14  Kinili      Milk    50  Azfresh     Milk_b  202002         0    0
```

Please help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you are after, but perhaps this is a start?

```
(df
 .assign(diff=lambda x: x.groupby(['Brand','Category','Partner','Product'])["MRP"].transform(lambda x: x.diff()))
 .fillna(0)
 .sort_values(['Brand','Category','Partner','Product', 'Yearweek'])
)
```

Comment: This gave me perfect values for diff columns.
If you can suggest how to derive the noofdays column as well, it'll be helpful